# One challenge encountered when dealing with the convergence of the AdaGrad-norm algorithm

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Given $\{X_{n},\mathcal{F}_{n}\}$ is an adapted process satisfying the following conditions:

1. $X_{n}>0,\ \forall\ n>0.$
2. There exists $ \epsilon>0,\  \sigma>0,$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n}^{2+\epsilon}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})\le \sigma.$
3. $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X^{2}_{k}\rightarrow+\infty\ a.s..$

Then can we acquire $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{X_{n}}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}^{2}}}=0\ \ a.s.?$